# Counting number of Arrays that contain the same two values

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift

Given a `Dictionary<String, Arrary<Int>>` find the how many entries have the same two specified values in the first `5` entries in the `Array<Int>`.

**For example:**

Given:

```
let numberSeries = [

    "20022016": [07,14,36,47,50,02,05],
    "13022016": [16,07,32,36,41,07,09],
    "27022016": [14,18,19,31,36,04,05],

]
```

And the values: `7` and `36`, the result should be `2` since the first and second entry have both the values `7` and `36` in the first 5 entries of the entry's array.

I've tried to accomplish this many ways, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

This is my current attempt:

```
//created a dictionary with (key, values)

let numberSeries = [

"20022016": [07,14,36,47,50,02,05],
"13022016": [16,07,32,36,41,07,09],
"27022016": [14,18,19,31,36,04,05],

]

var a = 07  //number to look for
var b = 36  // number to look for

// SearchForPairAB // search for pair // Doesn't Work.                                  

var ab = [a,b] // pair to look for
var abPairApearedCount = 0

for (kind, numbers) in numberSeries {
    for number in numbers[0...4] {
         if number == ab {           //err: Cannot invoke '==' with argument listof type Int, @Value [Int]
             abPairApearedCount++
         }
     }
 }
```

This gives the error: `Cannot invoke '==' with argument listof type Int, @Value [Int]` on the line: `if number == ab`

Comment: by pair I mean the value "a" and value "b" in the same array, line, in the first 5 positions(thats why i used [0...4]). I separated the code in three parts, the first two look for individual numbers in the array, the last one, looking for the two numbers in the same array, i don't know how to write. I tried different things but didn't get it right. I need it to output the answer "2" as the numbers "a" and "b" appear together in two different lines. Hope this throws some light...

Comment: Well, as @MikeS says, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but the error is very plain - `ab` is an array of Ints , `number` is an Int. There is no way they are comparable.

Comment: think i sent my past comment as you were sending yours. Hope makes is clear, i don't want to compare the two values. i want to know how many times they appear in the same array. The example shows three arrays but I have thousands.

Comment: @Francisco I edited your question to try to clarify it based on your comments here. If I missed something or I got it wrong somehow, please let me know and I'll roll the edit back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `==` to compare an `Int` and `Array<Int>`, that just doesn't make any sense from a comparison perspective. There are lots of different ways you can achieve what you're trying to do though. In this case I'd probably use `map`/`reduce` to count your pairs.

The idea is to `map` the values in your `ab` array to `Bool` values determined by whether or not the value is in your `numbers` array. Then, `reduce` those mapped `Bool`s to a single value: `true` if they're all `true`, or `false`. If that `reduce`d value is `true`, then we found the pair so we increment the count.

```
var ab = [a,b] // pair to look for
var abPairApearedCount = 0

for (kind, numbers) in numberSeries {
    let found = ab.map({ number in
        // find is a built-in function that returns the index of the value
        // in the array, or nil if it's not found
        return find(numbers[0...4], number) != nil
    }).reduce(true) { (result, value: Bool) in
        return result && value
    }
    if found {
        abPairApearedCount++
    }
}
```

That can actually be compacted quite a bit by using some of Swift's more concise syntax:

```
var ab = [a,b] // pair to look for
var abPairApearedCount = 0

for (kind, numbers) in numberSeries {
    let found = ab.map({ find(numbers[0...4], $0) != nil }).reduce(true) { $0 && $1 }
    if found {
        abPairApearedCount++
    }
}
```

And, just for fun, can be compacted even further by using `reduce` instead of a `for-in` loop:

```
var ab = [a,b] // pair to look for
var abPairApearedCount = reduce(numberSeries, 0) { result, series in
    result + (ab.map({ find(series.1[0...4], $0) != nil }).reduce(true) { $0 && $1 } ? 1 : 0)
}
```

That's getting fairly unreadable though, so I'd probably expand some of that back out.

Comment: If you want to code-golf a bit further you can get rid of the `map` and merge it with the inner `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my FP solution, aimed at decomposing the problem into easily digestible and reusable bite-sized chunks:

First, we define a functor that trims an array to a given length:

```
func trimLength<T>(length: Int) -> ([T]) -> [T] {
    return { return Array($0[0...length]) }
}
```

Using this we can trim all the elements using `map(array, trimLength(5))`

Now, we need an predicate to determine if all the elements of one array are in the target array:

```
func containsAll<T:Equatable>(check:[T]) -> ([T]) -> Bool {
    return { target in
        return reduce(check, true, { acc, elem in return acc && contains(target, elem) })
    }
}
```

This is the ugliest bit of code here, but essentially it's just iterating over check and insuring that each element is in the target array.  Once we've got this we can use `filter(array, containsAll([7, 26]))` to eliminate all elements of the array that don't contain all of our target values.

At this point, we can glue the whole thing together as:

```
filter(map(numberSeries.values, trimLength(5)), containsAll([7, 36])).count
```

But long lines of nested functions are hard to read, let's define a couple of helper functions and a custom operator:

```
func rmap<S:SequenceType, T>(transform:(S.Generator.Element)->T) -> (S) -> [T] {
    return { return map($0, transform) }
}

func rfilter<S:SequenceType>(predicate:(S.Generator.Element)->Bool) -> (S) -> [S.Generator.Element] {
    return { sequence in return filter(sequence, predicate) }
}

infix operator <^> { associativity left }
func <^> <S, T>(left:S, right:(S)->T) -> T {
    return right(left)
}
```

And a convenience function to count it's inputs:

```
func count<T>(array:[T]) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
```

Now we can condense the whole thing as:

```
numberSeries.values <^> rmap(trimLength(5)) <^> rfilter(containsAll([7, 36])) <^> count
```